# How can I update an exterior workbook when I am working within the ThisWorkbook Module?

Tags: excel, vba, save

I am attempting to create a macro that will update a status tracker workbook when the current workbook is saved. While the functions of grabbing the data, opening the status tracker, pasting the data, then closing the tracker work when I attach the macro to a button, when I import the code to the ThisWorkbook Excel Object so that the macro will be run on save it appears to break when I am attempting to select the other workbook.

My code can be found below. The error that breaks the code is found on line 10, "Windows("StatusTracker.xlsm").Sheets("Data").Select" that brings back Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range. Note, the second workbook does open, but nothing happens due to the error. And yes I comment a lot.

Code is here:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'Select the Summary tab for capturing data
Sheets("Summary Tab").Select
'Select data
ActiveSheet.Range("M12:M14").Select
'Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
'Open the status tracker and data tab
Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\FOLDER\StatusTracker.xlsm"
Windows("StatusTracker.xlsm").Sheets("Data").Select
'Select where the info is to be pasted and paste transposed
ActiveSheet.Range("G2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G4").Select
Selection.Copy
'Edit the location here to coincide with the destination location
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:D4").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
'Format location to percentage
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:D4").NumberFormat = "0%"
'Select the original paste of the data and delete it
ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G4").Select
Selection.Delete
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
'Save and close the Status Tracker
Workbooks("StatusTracker.xlsm").Close SaveChanges:=True
'Kill copy and paste command
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

My fear is someone will inform me that functions called in the ThisWorkbook module only effect the chosen workbook and you cannot work outside of it. If that is the case, is there a way around this so that I can make this work?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? For example nothing happens to ActiveSheet.Range("M12:M14"). Also, I highly recommend not using code like .Select, .Paste and .Copy.

Comment: To fix your issue without improving the code, you could probably just replace Windows("StatusTracker.xlsm").Sheets("Data").Select with ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Select